# Find a zero divisor in $Z_7 [x]/I.$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $f (x) ∈ Z_7 [x]$ be the polynomial $x^2 + [3]x + [3]$ and let $I$ denote the principal
ideal generated by $f (x).$

Find a zero divisor in $Z_7 [x]/I.$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to factor $x^2 + 3x+3 \in \mathbb{F}_7[x]$ using the usual formula for quadratic polynomials (which works over *every* field of characteristic $\neq 2,3$).

Comment: $(x+[6])(x+[4])$

Comment: That's correct. So you have found two zero divisors.

Comment: How they are zero divisors.

Comment: $(x + [6]) (x + [4]) = x^2 + [3] x + [3] \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2 + [3] x + [3]}$

Comment: @vonbrand zero divisor means there exist $b\neq 0$ so that $ab$=0 but $ab$ is equal to $x^2 +[3]x+[3]$, I don't understand why do you take mod $(x^2+[3]x+[3])$

Comment: Recall the definition of quotient rings.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Clearly $\rm\: x = 1\:$ is root in $\rm\:\Bbb Z_7,\:$ so  $\rm\: f = gh\:$ is reducible, therefore, modulo $\rm\:f = gh\:$ we have $\rm\: gh \equiv 0\:$ but $\rm\:g,h\not\equiv 0,\:$ yielding the sought zero-divisor.

**Remark** $\ $ Generally $\rm\: R/I\:$ has no zero-divisors (i.e. is a domain) iff $\rm\:I\:$ is prime. And $\rm\:I = (p)\:$ is prime iff $\rm\:p\:$ is prime. Over a UFD (such as $\rm\,F[x]),\,$ $\rm\,p\:$ is prime iff $\rm\:p\:$ is irreducible.